# How to embed Jasper report into web application using iframe

Tags: iframe, web, web-applications, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have generated some reports using Jasper Server. Now i want to Embed the same into my web application. I have seen we can either embed the report using API call as well as it is possible using iframes. I red that iframe will be faster than API calls and i would like to use the same in my app.

How do i use iframes to embed the reports from jasper server? is it just using the report link or do i need to pass any parameters along with the url. please assist me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a [wiki](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api) that provides details on embedding reports in iframes using the HTTP API

Answer (score 1):

```
YOUR_INSTANCE/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=REPORT_LOCATION&decorate=no&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin&viewAsDashboardFrame=false&PARAM_1=PARAM_1_VALUE&PARAM_2=PARAM_2_VALUE
```

Put this inside a iframe.
`YOUR_INSTANCE` - Your server instance, which u use to access the server from the web browser.
`REPORT_LOCATION` - Just run the report from the server. You can find the value for "reportUnit" in your address bar.
`PARAM_1` - report Parameter name. This should be the exact name you created in the input controller(in jasper server)
`PARAM_1_VALUE` - value for the parameters.